# Background color outside of viewport?

Tags: html, css, animation, background

When scrolling to the top or bottom in a webpage the background image ends and there is white "behind" the image. The background fills the entire webpage, that is not the issue.

How do i make the background image continue past the viewport?

I have a color gradiant that is animated with css like this:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #d20000, #004261) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: 250% 250%;
  -webkit-animation: bgcolor 10s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: bgcolor 10s ease infinite;
  animation: bgcolor 10s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bgcolor {
    0%{background-position:14% 0%}
    50%{background-position:87% 100%}
    100%{background-position:14% 0%}
}
@-moz-keyframes bgcolor {
    0%{background-position:14% 0%}
    50%{background-position:87% 100%}
    100%{background-position:14% 0%}
}
@keyframes bgcolor {
    0%{background-position:14% 0%}
    50%{background-position:87% 100%}
    100%{background-position:14% 0%}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: maybe by adding a fixed element in top and footer, and use z-index to put it behind everything, and then putting color on that element? just a thought

Comment: that would extend the image as such, but it could create the illusion that the body is being extended into the rubber banding

Comment: I don't want to have 3 separate pieces since it's aminating there would be stitches in the gradient. Optimally I would like to extend the animated gradient outside of the viewport somehow.